# How to put environmental variables in .gyp files when compiling Chromium?

Tags: environment-variables, chromium, gyp

I'm trying to compile Chromium with custom flags passed to the compiler (by modifying `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS`).  According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypUserDocumentation#Add_settings_to_a_target), I can do this via making a `.gyp` file in the appropriate location containing something like:

```
  {
    'targets': [
      {
        'target_name': 'existing_target',
        'conditions': [
          ['OS=="win"', {
            'cflags': [
              '/WX',
            ],
          }, { # OS != "win"
            'cflags': [
              '-Werror',
            ],
          }],
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

The trouble I have is that the value I want to pass in `CFLAGS` **depends on environmental variables**.

So I basically need to do the *equivalent* of

```
export CFLAGS="-flag1 '$HOME/foo/bar' -flag2 '$MY_PATH' $MORE_FLAGS"
```

except I can't, because it doesn't seem like environmental variables in dictionary values are expanded.
(And I obviously don't want to hard-code the values, since that defeats the point of making them environmental variables that I can easily change later...)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Would a command expansion work? https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/InputFormatReference#Command_Expansions_(<!,_<!@) (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361735/what-does-this-gyp-syntax-mean)

Comment: @IanHunter: I think so! Unfortunately I don't need this question answered anymore (and I don't have the code on my machine anymore) so I can't really test :( feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it anyway, since it looks correct.